# Is it possible to extend Eclipse Search Menu

Tags: eclipse, search, menu, extend, eclipse-jdt

right now in eclipse it is not possible to extend Menu defined by Other plugins by using eclipse extension:
org.eclipse.ui.menus.

I want to add one menu item in Search but not a search page. since the Menu Search is defined by org.eclipse.search, I cannot add it.

but I see JDT and CDT do add some menu item under search.  does any  body know how they make it work?

any hint is appreciated.

Comment: In Eclipse everything is possible :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend menus from other plugins using [org.eclipse.ui.actionSets](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_actionSets.htm) extension point

This is how the JDT does to extend the search menu with its own action. In order to have the action in a given menu you'll have to fill the `menubarPath` value. For example the JDT for the Java search action filled it with:

```
org.eclipse.search.menu/dialogGroup
```

I suggest to import the JDT UI sources and to look at the JDT plugin.xml file. FOr that you will need a classic Eclipse SDK and then in the plugins view right click on the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin and select import as source.

Comment: It's been stated elsewhere, but just for clarity, `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Update August 2012, as commented by [reprogrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130224/reprogrammer), `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` is deprecated:

> Instead, use the extension point [`org.eclipse.ui.commands`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_commands.html).

---

Original answer (August 2011)

The actionSet ([`extension point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets"`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_actionSets.html)) with an action on '`menubarPath="org.eclipse.search.menu/dialogGroup"`' recommended by [Manuel Selva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116388/manuel-selva) is the official solution, in line with [general menu contribution](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html).

But beware of some issue that might still lingering for *Search* menu contribution, as [illustrated by this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/21216/) around the (supposedly fixed) [bug 15684](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15684):
(it was in 2009, hopefully the issue has been addressed since)

> What actually *does* work is redefining the whole Search Menu as in the workaround that is still currently used in JDT 3.6:

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
      <actionSet
            label="%JavaSearchActionSet.label"
            description="%JavaSearchActionSet.description"
            visible="false"
            id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SearchActionSet">
<!-- see http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15684    -->
<!-- Note: The menu (re-) definition has to be here due to bug: -->
<!-- =================================================================== -->
<!-- Search Menu                                                         -->
<!-- =================================================================== -->
         <menu
               label="%searchMenu.label"
               path="navigate"
               id="org.eclipse.search.menu">
                <groupMarker name="internalDialogGroup"/>   <!-- not to be used by clients  -->
                <groupMarker name="dialogGroup"/>           <!-- to be used by clients      -->
                <separator name="fileSearchContextMenuActionsGroup"/> <!-- to be used by clients      -->
                <separator name="contextMenuActionsGroup"/> <!-- to be used by clients -->
                <separator name="occurencesActionsGroup"/> <!-- to be used by clients -->
                <separator name="extraSearchGroup"/> <!-- to be used by clients -->
         </menu>
<!-- (...) -->
```

Comment: great , thanks for your answer, but how I can control the visibility of my menu item like the menuitem 'C++', "Java" under Search. I try the 'visibility' element in the action , but it does not work.

Comment: @VonC: The extension point org.eclipse.ui.actionSets is now deprecated. See http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_actionSets.html

Comment: @VonC: Using the `org.eclipse.ui.menu` extension point for adding an item to an old menu that is contributed via `actionSets` is not straightforward. See my comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937322/is-it-possible-to-extend-eclipse-search-menu#comment15700341_6939032 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941278/adding-menu-item-in-eclipse#comment15700568_7941776 If you know how to use the new extension points for adding an item to an old menu like JDT Refactor or Search, please update your answer.

Comment: @reprogrammer I have seen your comment and had no direct solution. That would be best addressed in a new question.

Comment: @VonC: Fortunately, someone else has already asked the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7941278/130224

Comment: @reprogrammer: Unfortunately, the only answer is currently sitting at -1 and it isn't clear what the proper course of action is.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the ID of the menu or toolbar, you can extend these using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point. For the search menu, this ID is `org.eclipse.search.menu`. If you want to add stuff to the `dialogGroup` then use `org.eclipse.search.menu?after=dialogGroup`.

Comment: thanks, I redefine the Search menu following the JDT solution, now my menu item is shown under the Search .

Comment: @Tonny Madsen: I like the idea of using the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.menus` as opposed to `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` because the latter is deprecated (http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_actionSets.html). However, adding a menu item to a menu defined using actionSets seems a bit a different and the standard method that you suggested doesn't work for this purpose.