# Adding menu item in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

I want to write an Eclipse plug-in that adds an item to the **Refactor** menu in Eclipse JDT? How can I do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Write an eclipse plugin?

Comment: I am but how do I add an option for example "My new action" in the Refactor menu?

Comment: I don't know. But you might at least mention in your question that you want to write an eclipse plugin and that this plugin should add a new menu item. Your question sounds like some eclipse user wanting to put an arbitrary existing action in the menu.

Comment: For now thats what I want to do. I want to add an action item even if it doesn't do anything to show up in the Refactor menu. I will then go on to implementing it. Do you know how to add an action item in Refactor menu?

Comment: also, different languages sometimes contribute different Refactor menus.  Which language are you editing?

Comment: I am working in Java- Eclipse

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6937322/130224

Comment: Hint: There are some partial instructions at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Search_Menu

Comment: Note: A solution that uses the deprecated extension `actionSets` has been already proposed: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6937322/130224 Please propose a solution using the new extension `org.eclipse.ui.menus`.

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I was writing a plug-in that performs some re factoring.

Writing the refactoring was not too complicated, but figuring out how add the menu items correctly into the Refactor menu took a lot of time.

Here is the correct plugin.xml snippet:

The Refactor menu tag is a copy of the original "Refactor" menu definition from org.eclipse.jdt.ui. It is important to copy all the separator definitions. For my plug-in, I have also added a new separator called spartanGroup.

The path for the Refactor menu is org.eclipse.jdt.ui.refactoring.menu.

It is possible to figure this information by looking at plugin.xml of the org.eclipse.jdt.ui plug-in. You can find it online (for example here) or you can import the source code of your eclipse build following these steps:

```
1 File -> Import
2 Select Plug-ins and Fragments and click next.
3 In the "Import From" section choose "The active target platform".
4 In the "Import As" section choose "Project with source folders"
5 In the next screen, locate your plug-in (org.eclipse.jdt.ui) and add it.
6 Click finish and the source code of the plug-in will be imported into your workspace.
```

[image: plugin.xml]

Comment: Hmm, I think I tried that (found it online somewhere before) but it didn't work. Will check again just to be sure.

Comment: by the way the source of this answer: http://www.nihamkin.com/2013/02/16/how-to-add-items-into-eclipse-s-refactor-menu/

Answer (score -2):

You could write a plug-in that utilizes the Platform Command Framework. For details see the official wiki page, that provides several tutorial links: http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Platform_Command_Framework

Basically, you define a command to execute, a menu contribution (where to display it) and a command handler (what to execute).

Comment: No, adding a menu item to an existing menu contributed via `actionSets` is more involved. Thus, the following configuration that you suggested doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/3260685