# I want to extend the Eclipse Search menu using the extension point org.eclipse.ui.commands

Tags: eclipse, search, extend, eclipse-juno, eclipse-indigo

I have a plugin that extends the Eclipse Search menu in Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) using the extension point org.eclipse.ui.actionSets. Given that actionSets are deprecated in Eclipse 3.8 and 4.2 (Juno) and Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler), I would like to scrap the actionSets implementation and replace it using the extension point org.eclipse.ui.commands.

However, this doesn't seem (and isn't) straight forward. If I use a locationURI that points to any other menu, I can see the new commands that I have added. However, the Search menu is adamant and I am unable to extend it!

Any suggestions?

I have read the questions raised at [Is it possible to extend Eclipse Search Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937322/is-it-possible-to-extend-eclipse-search-menu) and [Adding menu item in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941278/adding-menu-item-in-eclipse) but there doesn't appear to be a solution.

Some background at: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/21216/

Comment: Looking at the Search Menu in my Eclipse 4.3 everything is still being done with action sets.

Comment: So, Eclipse is happy to use deprecated features? Well well.

Comment: Eclipse is huge and many things have not been updated. I think in this case the action set deprecation is mainly to help with seeing if code can be moved easily to the Eclipse 4 'e4' API which does not have action sets at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some investigation, I discovered that the Search menu can be *redefined*.

```
<menuContribution locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=Navigate">
    <menu 
        id="org.eclipse.search.menu"
        label="Search">
        <separator name="dialogGroup"/>
    </menu>
</menuContribution>
```

The one minor disadvantage with this solution is that the menu items in the Search menu are rearranged depending on where the new menu items are added.